# JSlider-Advice needed

Tags: java, swing, jslider

I appreciate the advice I received for my previous question. I have one more question. I want to draw a face, a round pink face. On that round pink face I want to add a red smile. And I want to elongate or shorten that smile using a JSlider. My previous question dealt with ALIGNING circle A's centre with circle B and using JSlider to increase or decrease the radius of circle B in such a way that the centres of circles A and B always coincide. I understand the answer that I got. But how do I FIX a smile (ie an ARC) on a face (ie an OVAL) so that the JSlider elongates or shortens the smile BUT DOES NOT MOVE THAT SMILE ALL OVER THE FACE. In other words, the smile must stay fixed on the face. Please, I need advice. My (wrong) code is:

```
    public void createGUI() {
    slider1Label = new JLabel("Mouth width(10-100): ");
    window.add(slider1Label);

    slider1 = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL,10,100,10);
    window.add(slider1);
    slider1.addChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {

    Graphics paper = panel.getGraphics();
    int slider1Value = slider1.getValue();
    paper.setColor(Color.white);
    paper.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);


    paper.setColor(Color.pink); // draw the pink interior of the face
    paper.fillOval(50,50,200,200);
    paper.setColor(Color.black); // draw the black exterior border of the face
    paper.drawOval(50,50,200,200);


    paper.setColor(Color.red); // draw the red mouth
    paper.fillArc(90,140,220-slider1Value,150-slider1Value,20,-220);
    }
```

Comment: 1) You use geometry. Really, it's just a matter of simple math. 2) Please try to work the math out on paper before committing it to code. 3) You don't draw on a JPanel by calling `getGraphics()` on it since the Graphics object obtained will not persist. To see what I mean, minimize and then refresh your program and watch all your pretty drawings disappear. Draw inside of the JPanel's `paintComponent(...)` method just as the tutorials will show you.

Comment: The radius of the smile should relative to the radius of the face, or, a proportion of it.  So when the face radius changes, you should be able to calculate the radius and position of the smile. From there, you need to determine the start angle and extent of the smile based on the values returned from `JSlider`. Remember, 0" is at the 3o'clock position ;)

Comment: My appreciation to both "Hovercraft Full Of Eels" and "MadProgrammer".

Comment: @JCDyson Apart from commenting, accept and/or upvote the answers that helped you. Also, your titles should be more specific. I'd recommend reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask